# Windows 11 Switch language shortcut works only after 2 presses

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, input-languages, windows-11

Since windows 11 a weird bug seems to occur, and it only occurs after some time.

So I have 2 languages - EN and HE.
I'm using Alt+Shift and everything works well - it switches between the 2 languages, but after some time (hours? days?) suddenly pressing Alt+Shift keeps the same language layout, and only after another Alt+Shift it changes to the other language.
When I press again Alt+Shift it switches normally, but another press of Alt+Shift keeps the same layout and I need to press again Alt+Shift.

This is the most annoying bug cause I can't rely on the switch language to work on the first press.
Anyone else encountered such weird bug? Anyone have nay idea how to fix it?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I have this too and it's annoying. I started using windows 11 a month ago.

Comment: I also have this issue...and the bug is pretty much there all the time.